# Windows Phone 7 emulator with a touchscreen

Tags: emulation, windows-phone-7, touchscreen

I'm thinking about getting a small [touchscreen](http://www.mimomonitors.com/products/imo-pivot-touch) to work with the [Windows Phone 7 emulator](http://developer.windowsphone.com/windows-phone-7/)... but will the developers tools support multi-touch from a touchscreen?  I've only seen it with single mouse clicks so far...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[It appears so. YMMV](http://www.machackpc.com/featured/multitouch-on-windows-phone-7-series-emulator/)

Answer (score 1):

It works for me as well. I'm using a [Dell Latitude XT2](http://www.dell.com/tablet/) laptop and multitouch gestures, such as pinch zoom, work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

works like a champ for me! i'm using one of the pdc tablets and it works great!

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on my 21.5' HP touchscreen monitor.
I definitely felt the purchase was worth it for developing WP7 apps.

Comment: Oops... make that a 21 **inch** monitor. :)